# how to verify a Twilio call using the parent account token

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I have a Twilio account that has a sub-account.
When I'm validating the incoming request from Twilio and use the sub-account's token, the function returns true - request is valid.
When I try to use the parent token, the function always returns a false answer.

I'm using Node.js, Twilio version "3.18.0"

```
twilioClient.validateExpressRequest(req, authToken, options);
```

Has anyone been able to verify requests for all sub-accounts using the parent token? The API suggests that working with the parent token is possible in some cases by providing SID as well, but I couldn't find anything regarding the validation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Even though some API calls can be called on behalf of the parent account by providing the parent sid, Twilio does not support verification using parent token, the signature calculation is based on the token of the account the request came from (sub-account in this case).